# Register click and hold on a tile in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

I have a procedurally generated tilemap that the player can interact with through mouse clicks. Each time the player clicks I get its screen position convert it to world cords and find the correct tile. This is fine but only works with single clicks and has no idea about a continuous hold of the mouse.

I am trying to figure out how to have a timed system like click and hold, both Minecraft and Terraira have ideas of break progress for each block / tile which is what I really want.

Anyone have an Idea how to track this and reset it when the player releases the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing your own raycasting when the pointer goes down and then calling your interaction method, add a monobehaviour to each of your tiles that implements the IPointerDownHandler, IPointerExitHandler, and IPointerUp handler. Make sure you have an eventhandler in the scene, and a physcisRaycaster on your active camera!

OnPointerDown -> set a time stamp to time.unscaledTime

OnPointerExit -> reset timestamp to -1 or what ever (some religious coders would prefere a nullable float, so then set it to null), to cancel the interaction

OnPointerUp -> if your timer is > -1 (or NOT null), check if time.unscaledTime - your time stamp > your time threshold, if so -> call your interaction method. Reset the timer

More logic can be added of course.

EDIT:
from your comment, since you don’t want to have the logic per-tile, instead, when you click, save the tile that is “in world position of the screen position click”, and WHILE the mouse is down, check (in some frequency, per frame or every few ms), if the pointer is STILL on the same tile. if so, keep your timer running, otherwise reset it. if the timer expires, your interaction may start. if the pointer goes up, reset

Comment: This would probably work but my tilemap renders about 18432 at once meaning I would need to have that many gameobjects in the scene... which of course would make the game unplayable and would also make moving to new areas(which generates more tiles) reall slow.